# Failure to write into specific S3 folder

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Following is my lambda function for reading the original file uploaded in the media/images folder and creating two files - thumbnail, preview and upload back to the same folder media/images.

Creating thumbnail works, except it's getting created at the S3 root instead of /tmp. And hence, the second part of the function - to copy the newly created files from /tmp to media/images is not working.

I use the same bucket for both original, and low-resolution images. Following is my lambda function. Any help appreciated. Lambda function has all the permissions in the S3 bucket.

```
import json
import uuid
import boto3

from PIL import Image

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Started the Lambda function to create thumbnails!")
    
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    print('source_bucket: {0}\nkey: {1}'.format(source_bucket, key))
    #key prints the complete path of the uploaded file
    
    txt_splits = key.split('/')#split by directory names
    print("txt_splits: {0}".format(txt_splits))
    
    src_file_name = txt_splits[len(txt_splits)-1]#get just the file name + extension
    src_file_ext = src_file_name.split('.', 1)[1]#get extention from the file name
    fname_no_extention = src_file_name.split('.',1)[0]#get file name with no extension

    print("src_file_name: {0}, fname_no_extention: {1}, src_file_ext: {2}".format(src_file_name, fname_no_extention, src_file_ext))
    
    tgt_file_name = r"{0}_thumbnail.{1}".format(fname_no_extention, src_file_ext)
    tgt_preview_file_name = r"{0}_preview.{1}".format(fname_no_extention, src_file_ext)
    
    print("tgt_file_name: {0}, tgt_preview_file_name: {1}".format(tgt_file_name, tgt_preview_file_name))
    
    tmp_file_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '_' + src_file_name
    tmp_download_path = '/tmp/{0}'.format(tmp_file_name)
    
    print("tmp_download_path: {0}".format(tmp_download_path))
    
    with open(tmp_download_path, 'wb') as img_file:
        s3_client.download_fileobj(source_bucket, key, img_file)
    
    thumbnail_image_and_path = '/tmp/{0}'.format(tgt_file_name)
    print("thumbnail_image_and_path: {0}".format(thumbnail_image_and_path))
    
    preview_image_and_path = "/tmp/{0}".format(tgt_preview_file_name)
    print("preview_image_and_path: {0}".format(preview_image_and_path))
    
    src_tn_image = Image.open(tmp_download_path)
    original_width, original_height = src_tn_image.size
    print("original_width: {0}, original_height: {1}".format(original_width, original_height))
    
    thumbnail_width = original_width
    thumbnail_height = original_height
    
    preview_width = original_width
    preview_height = original_height
    
    if original_width > original_height: #landscape
        aspect_ratio = int(original_width/original_height)
        thumbnail_width = 512
        thumbnail_height = thumbnail_width * (original_height / original_width)
        
        if original_width > 1280:
            preview_width = 1280
        
        preview_height = preview_width * (original_height / original_width)
    elif original_height > original_width: #portrait
        thumbnail_height = 512
        thumbnail_width = thumbnail_height * (original_width / original_height)
        
        if original_height > 960:
            preview_height = 960
        
        preview_width = preview_height * (original_width / original_height)
    else: #square
        thumbnail_height = 512
        thumbnail_width = 512
        
        if original_width > 1280:
            preview_width = 1280
            preview_height = 1280
    
    print("thumbnail_width: {0}, thumbnail_height: {1}".format(thumbnail_width, thumbnail_height))
    print("preview_width: {0}, preview_height: {1}".format(preview_width, preview_height))
    
    src_tn_image.thumbnail((thumbnail_width, thumbnail_height))
    src_tn_image.save(thumbnail_image_and_path)
    print("thumbnail image created and saved, moving to preview image...")
    
    src_pv_image = Image.open(tmp_download_path)
    src_pv_image.thumbnail((preview_width, preview_height))
    src_pv_image.save(preview_image_and_path)

    print("preview image created and saved, uploading them to the target path...")
    
    s3_client.upload_file(thumbnail_image_and_path, source_bucket, tgt_file_name)
    s3_client.upload_file(preview_image_and_path, source_bucket, tgt_preview_file_name)
    
    print("Completed all thumbnail generation operations, quitting!")
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Comment: You're calling `upload_file()` with `tgt_file_name`, which is just a filename.  If you want to upload it to some other location in S3, use something like  `s3_client.upload_file(preview_image_and_path, source_bucket, 'media/images/' + tgt_file_name)`

Comment: @AnonCoward: Thanks, do you know why the following code is not creating those thumbnails and preview files at the tmp folder, and instead, they create those files at the root of the bucket?     with open(tmp_download_path, 'wb') as img_file:
        s3_client.download_fileobj(source_bucket, key, img_file)

Comment: Those two lines of code do nothing to create a file anywhere on S3.  They download from S3 to the local filesystem.